Task Scheduler issue on windows 10 and windows 11
I need to create a task in Task Scheduler to run the following code, which will mount a shared drive upon logon. The task is successfully created in Task Scheduler; however, it remains in a "ready" state and does not run when I log in using Azure credentials. I'm unsure why this is happening and would appreciate any input on resolving this issue.
$DriveLetter = "Z:"
$NetworkPath = "Network Path"
$Username = 'Username'
$Password = 'Password'

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePassword)

# Action using simplified command for testing
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -Command `"New-PSDrive -Name '$DriveLetter' -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '$NetworkPath' -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('$Username',(ConvertTo-SecureString '$Password' -AsPlainText -Force))) -Persist`""
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "UserID" -LogonType INTERACTIVE
# Trigger, Principal, and Settings
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn

$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries

# Register task
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Principal $Principal -Settings $Settings -TaskName "MapNetworkDriveOnLogon" -Description "Maps network drive $DriveLetter at logon with credentials"


Is the task created? And what if you create the task manually? Does it work then? Usually when I need to create a task using Powershell, I create the task first, then export it to xml and create the task in powershell using that xml.

We need to create the task and push it to the many computers through Ninjarmm and hence I prefer powershell. I will try this and let you know how it goes

Yes, I've done it myself using Powershell. You create the xml first, then you encode the xml with base64 then in your script, you create a new xml file by decoding the base64 and out-file, then you import the xml, then remove the xml.
